# Failure saving state: active TestFragment{978450f} has cleared index: -1

Tags: android, android-fragments

This error occurs when I open an activity from a fragment. App crashes after that activity loaded.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TestActivity.class);
getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

On Going through stack overflow found that this happens while trying fragment transaction where we don't have reference to the correct instance of a fragment. But I haven't done any fragment transaction in that activity. When this error will occur and how to handle it?

Error Log:

> 11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active
>   TestFragment{1fa01248} has cleared index: -1      11-29 10:11:43.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1767)
>   11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:527)
>   11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1298)
>   11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1288)
>   11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:3958)
>   11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3369)
>   11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425)
>   11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 11-29
>   10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
>   11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 11-29
>   10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 11-29 10:11:43.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 11-29
>   10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 11-29 10:11:43.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 11-29 10:11:43.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   11-29 10:11:43.786: E/AndroidRuntime(18088):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: show your complete code, and logcat of error

Comment: Already have answers to this question in stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205335/handling-and-mitigating-illegalstateexception-failure-saving-state-active-fr and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436120/failure-saving-state-target-not-in-fragment-manager-settargetfragment and you can find another answers by following url : https://www.google.as/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Fragment+Failure+saving+state:+active

Comment: @ mr.boyfox thats what i had mentioned, i gone through these links but it didn’t work out. I didn’t do any fragment transaction inside my activity other than instantiating the activity (getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent,100))