# Is there ever a good reason to use the Child Fragment Manager for DialogFragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

Normally when showing a DialogFragment from an Activity, you do this:

```
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(args);             
myDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), MY_TAG);
```

Or if you are in a Fragment, you can do this:

```
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(args);             
myDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), MY_TAG);
```

Which as far as I can tell is pretty similar to the first since it's finding the Activity and then calling from it.

However, again, assuming we're in a Fragment, would it ever make sense to launch a DialogFragment by doing this instead:

```
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(args);             
myDialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), MY_TAG);
```

Would the calling Fragment be considered the parent of the DialogFragment?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to some issues when using setTargetFragment and then calling getTargetFragment()

see this post with its answer
[Failure saving state - target not in fragment manager (setTargetFragment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436120/failure-saving-state-target-not-in-fragment-manager-settargetfragment)